# Python docs, inserting mulitple pics in a table, issue with footer

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, docx

I managed to write a code in order to import multiple pics inside a cell in a table, but for some reason, instead of getting inserted on the next page, the last picture is overflowing into the footer. I'm enclosing a screenshot which will make this clearer.

[image]

I'm using Google Colab for below codes.

```py
document = Document('Test.docx')
tables=document.tables
for i in range(1, len(tables)):
    for ro in tables[i].rows:
        step = ro.cells[0].text.replace('.', '').strip()
        
        for pic_name in keys:
          if step in pic_name :
            p = ro.cells[2].add_paragraph() #retour à la ligne
            p = ro.cells[2].add_paragraph()
            r = p.add_run()
            r.add_picture(pic_name, width=Inches(4.3))
            
            p = ro.cells[2].add_paragraph()
document.save("Test.docx")  # Save file
```

I'm using Word 365, but I noticed that this issue doesn't happen on Word 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the "Allow row to break across pages" ?

To change the option:

- Select the whole table by clicking once in the table and then on the table selector
- From the Table Tools, Layout tab, Table group, click the Properties icon
- From the Table Properties dialog box, select the Row tab;
- Select the option 'Allow Row to break across pages'
- Click OK

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. This setting is already "on"....